# Conditional formatting at row level

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2000 rows of cost price data. In each row, I would like to apply a color scale to quickly highlight cost prices (from low to high). However, I would like the color scale comparison logic each time to be applied within a specific row. So row 12 data should not be compared to row 13 data for instance. How can I do this without creating 2000 rules stipulating each row?

I have done it for the first row as below:

D3:BL3

However, when I try $D3:$BL2000 and hit "Done" the $ signs just disappear meaning the formatting logic isn't applied at row level but all rows (so e.g. row 4 is compared to e.g. row 100).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a conditional formatting with scale color row by row with Google Sheets option. You can simulate it with the help of MIN, MAX and QUARTILE. Here you have an example:

```
=(D1=MAX($D1:$Z1))*(D1<>"")
=(D1>QUARTILE($D1:$Z1,3))*(D1<>"")
=(D1>QUARTILE($D1:$Z1,2))*(D1<>"")
=(D1>QUARTILE($D1:$Z1,1))*(D1<>"")
=(D1>MIN($D1:$Z1))*(D1<>"")
=(D1=MIN($D1:$Z1))*(D1<>"")
```

[image]

PS: remember to sort accordingly the rules. In the top the highest values (in green in my example) and in the bottom the lowest values
PPS: you could do something similar with the help of RANK or LARGE/SMALL, depending on your data